Sucessful compilation but browser can't access site
I am doing my first project with Django and React. Whenever i run
npm run dev

the project compiles succesfully. But once I go to the browser, it says that the site can't be reached and that
localhost rejected the conection.

I tried running
PORT=8001 npm run dev

but the same keeps happening.
I have read other options about changing the webpack.config.js file, like this
devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    compress: true,
    port: 3000,
    open: true,
  },

but my project has no dist folder

React and Django must be different projects running in different ports.
By default react runs in on port 3000 with the command npm run dev and django on 8000 with the command python manage.py runserver.
Then you can develop your front-end and back-end separately like that:
Front-end: localhost:3000
Back-end:  localhost:8000

When you run the frontend, it will give a success message in terminal and with the port url like:
Local: http://localhost:3000
On Your Network: http://192.168.1.100:3000
Make sure to copy the local one and paste it on your browser.
Django Server port after python manage.py runserver:
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
